# Difference between Concrete Knowledge Object and Abstract Knowledge Object?

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge, data-model

What is the difference between Concrete Knowledge Object and Abstract Knowledge Object ?

> KnowledgeArticle and KnowledgeArticleVersion - Abstract Knowledge
> Objects.
>
> Knowledge__ka and Knowledge__kav - Concrete Knowledge Objects.

In terms of the data they hold is it any different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same from a standard fields standpoint, but you can have separate customizations for concrete Knowledge Objects.

So you can have for example different layouts and different Custom fields.

In Salesforce Classic there were only 2 objects and we used Record Types and different Knowledge articles, in Lightning Knowledge Salesforce decided to introduce different SObjects for concrete Knowledge types for more flexibility and customization